# Flutter: ScrollAppBar showing wrong size when launched on Android Emulator with Android version (11 API 30)

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I installed Android 11 on pixel 4 , and launched my app on it for testing. But the `ScrollAppBar` was sized wrongly. I noticed there was no problem when using AppBar. So the problem should be from `ScrollAppBar` plugin. I used `kToolBarHeight` to specify the height of the app. The app works properly on other devices.

Is this the problem with the plugin, or my app? I am unable to share the pic due to security reasons. Have anyone come out with a solution for this problem?